# DeprecationWarning: `open()` is deprecated in mongoose >= 4.11.0，use `openUri()` instead, or set the `useMongoClient`

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I use the MongoDB in my Node.js project, when I run `node app.js` in my project there comes an issue like bellow:

> DeprecationWarning: `open()` is deprecated in mongoose >= 4.11.0，use `openUri()` instead, or set the `useMongoClient` option if using `connect()` or `createConnection()`

My core codes:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
var db = mongoose.connection

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connect error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
    console.log('connect success');
})
```

Answer (score 12):

From http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html :

```
const options = {
  useMongoClient: true,
  autoIndex: false, // Don't build indexes
  reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE, // Never stop trying to reconnect
  reconnectInterval: 500, // Reconnect every 500ms
  poolSize: 10, // Maintain up to 10 socket connections
  // If not connected, return errors immediately rather than waiting for reconnect
  bufferMaxEntries: 0
};
mongoose.connect(uri, options);
```

When you connect mongodb, you should add `{useMongoClient:true}`:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test',{useMongoClient:true})
```

Answer (score 0):

I also face the similar type of Error.
Solution : I update the version from mongoose@4 to mongoose5 . After upgrading the version of mongoose the problem has been solved . you may apply my solution it may help resolve your problem .

How i update my mongoose version :
first [goto npm mongoose official website](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose)  copy the latest version of mongoose (at my time the latest version is 5.12.13). and paste in package.json file with mongoose version module and run **npm install** .After installation of all the packages . I run my application using **run index.js** the problem resolved . I Hope my suggestion will help you .